# There is any possibility to start TestNGCucumberRunner programmatically

Tags: scala, cucumber, sbt, testng, cucumber-jvm

I want to use io.cucumber.cucumber-testng to start cucumber tests programmatically. I want to start this run from a Scala app.

I could only start the run by bootstrapping the TestNGCucumberRunner from outside the Scala app.

Update:

I wrote a piece of code in C# for the NUnit engine. I want something similar but to be able to start the tests from Scala (all the infrastructure is Java code). I am nub with scala and sbt and have minimal experience with TestNg (if Junit is more suitable for what I want, I can use it).
Maybe another side question. Is there any possibility of passing custom parameters programmatically to testNg or Junit? Like in C# Nunit "package.AddSetting("TestParameters", customRunParametersString);". These parameters can be read during test execution using (TestContext.Parameters).

```
using (ITestEngine engine = TestEngineActivator.CreateInstance()) {
                    ITestFilterService filterService = engine.Services.GetService<ITestFilterService>();
                    engine.WorkDirectory = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    TestPackage package = new TestPackage(dictionaryParameters["ProjectName"] + ".dll");
                    ITestFilterBuilder builder = filterService.GetTestFilterBuilder();
                    builder.SelectWhere(dictionaryParameters["Tag"]);

                    package.AddSetting("TestParameters", customRunParametersString);
                    TestFilter filter = builder.GetFilter();
                    ITestRunner runner = engine.GetRunner(package);
                    Console.WriteLine(@"TEST RUN STARTED : Feature " + dictionaryParameters["Tag"]);
                    result = runner.Run(null, filter);

                    Console.WriteLine(@"TEST RUN FINISH : Feature " + dictionaryParameters["Tag"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Remaining runtime ".ToUpper() + context.RemainingTime.Minutes + @" minutes  and" + context.RemainingTime.Seconds + @"seconds");
                }
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you tried and what's not working? Share some code sample that you tried. And also what you'd like to be able to do.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do.

If you want to run Cucumber programmatically and don't really care about the framework you use, then using the JUnit Platform Launcher API from JUnit 5 isn't a bad choice.

You would add `io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine` as a dependency and then execute Cucumber through the JUnit Platform API.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine

```java
public class RunCucumber {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = request()
              .selectors(
                      selectDirectory("path/to/features")
              )
              .build();

      Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
      SummaryGeneratingListener listener = new SummaryGeneratingListener();
      launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener);
      launcher.execute(request);

      TestExecutionSummary summary = listener.getSummary();
      // Do something with summary

   }

}
```

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I need. Thanks! Do you have a suggestion for the last part of my question? "Is there any possibility of passing custom parameters programmatically to testNg or Junit? Like in C# Nunit "package.AddSetting("TestParameters", customRunParametersString);.". These parameters can be read during test execution using (TestContext.Parameters)." . I have searched in the documentation but have not found any functionality that will allow me to provide custom parameters to the engine. I use the env variable for the moment.

Comment: You currently can not do that.